# I need 2048bit primes in order to test the upper limits of my RSA program

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, primes

I've just finished a project which is to be in by tomorrow, it's a working RSA encryption system. However, in a massive error I have included a prime number generator, I just use numbers which are generated on the internet. So far every prime I've used has been fine but obviously I'd like to check it with far larger primes than I've been using (1024 bits is the largest I've been able to find). **Could anyone who has a working prime number generator just post 2 2048 bit primes for me to use to check** so that I can add it to my write-up before tomorrow morning? I know that this possibly isn't the correct place to ask this but I couldn't think of anywhere else to go. Thanks a lot (and I'm trusting you all to post actual prime numbers and not just troll me <3 ).

Comment: Not an appropriate place for such a request. I would imagine there are [unofficial] RSA test/data suites available.

Comment: I know it's not suitable, I'm sorry but I'm **really** short on time now and I'm sure there are people here who can help me and are nice enough to do so. I'm sorry

Comment: Primes that will fit in 2048 bits or primes that are greater than 2^2048?

Answer (score 4):

Use the NextPrime function at Wolfram|Alpha. For instance, the next prime larger than 2^2048 + 2^217 is [NextPrime[2^2048 + 2^217]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NextPrime%5B2%5E2048+%2B+2%5E217%5D).

**EDIT:** I looked again at Wolfram|Alpha. It gave me a message that the standard computation time was exceeded, and asked me to buy additional computation time, but also gave the correct answer after just waiting for a few seconds. In any event, here are the next primes larger than 2^2048 + 2^217 and 2^2048 + 2^593; I made the computations myself, and verified them with Wolfram|Alpha:

32317006071311007300714876688669951960444102669715484032130345427524655138867890
89319720141152291346368871796092189801949411955915049092109508815238644828312063
08773673009960917501977503896521067960576383840675682767922186426197561618380943
38476170470581645852036305042887575891541065808607552399123930385521914333389668
34242068497478656456949485617603532632205807780565933102619270846031415025859286
41771167259436037184618573575983511523016459044036976132332872312271256847108202
09725157101726931323469678542580656697935045997268352998638215525166389647960126
939249806625440700685819469589938384356951833568218188663

32317006071311007300714876688669951960444102669715484032130345427524655138867890
89319720141152291346368871796092189801949411955915049092109508815238644828312063
08773673009960917501977503896521067960576383840675682767922186426197561618380943
38476170470581645852036305042887575891541065808607552399123930385521914333389668
34242068497478656456949485617603532632205807780565933102619270846031415025859286
41771167259436037184618573575983511523340639947855803707216654176622128812031049
45914551140008147396357886767669820042828793708588252247031092071155540224751031
064253209884099238184688246467489498721336450133889385773

Comment: It exceeds the standard computation time and can't be done without buying extra computation time. I have the app on my phone but even with extra time on my phone Wolfram can't do it.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
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
```

and:

```
0xceb052c9732614fee3c0a197a5ae0fcd83422243918ab83bc678656ae0344232a7c1070b7d5aabaae2bda96bf590da4830238b606f24b29626f1bfa00cce39f5f9bb9c1c3ead98f2055e373abf01e1fe1c816e12e0ed13791461c435123dad8cbe80e474f753aa9d115a8b93c167adceaee5a18ceedef88d307427fc495d9e44d4268ba83c4a65c4667b7df79f342639da3ddd2777926848855ca0068668efe7f27d65f455074c960bbc168bfb3a1225cd6f42585ddba6b3484f36707524133b81dd01d062591fec1b756766aeebe667bf9e2480eebb5964bc5eaff4b165e142772ce64b229a7258667a3964f08e06dfbfe3e3c1cf918395b89c1fdb18907711
```

Generated using OpenSSL by creating a 4096 bit key (which is comprised of 2048 bit primes):

`openssl genrsa 4096 | openssl rsa -text`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use any RSA key pair generator that outputs the CRT parameters, since P and Q - the primes - are part of the output.

Comment: Answering this as it came up on the close vote queue.